# Get relative path to every file in a directory

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How do I get the relative path to every file in a certain directory? If I use `Dir["path/to/folder/*"]` it outputs the whole path.

Comment: Relative to the current directory or relative to `path/to/folder`?

Comment: Relative to the current directory would probably be best.

Answer (score 5):

[`Dir#entries`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-entries) is probably what you are looking for:

```
Dir.entries("dir").each { |f| puts f }
# ⇒ Makefile
# ⇒ text.doc
# ⇒ ...
```

Please be aware that the result may contain `.` and `..`. To prevent appearance of those in the result, you might want to use `Array#reject` (creds to @iain, the snippet will filter all *hidden* files on *nices):

```
Dir.entries("dir").reject{ |e| e.start_with? '.' }.each { |f| puts f }
```

Other option is to [`Dir#chdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) before executing `glob`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `entries` expects a directory name, not a pattern. You have to remove the `/*` unless there is a directory with that name.

Comment: `reject` is useful when using `entries` e.g. `Dir.entries("dir").reject{|e| e.start_with? "." }.each{`…